# C Program with Bitwise Operators Only Functions Correctly with Debug Statements

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, bitwise-operators

I am trying to solve this challenge:

**Task:**
Given set S = {1, 2, 3, ...n}, find:

- the maximum value of **a** & **b**, which is less than a given integer **k**, where
  **a** and **b** are two integers from set **s**.
- the maximum value of **a** | **b**, which is less than a given integer **k**, where
  **a** and **b** are two integers from set **s**.
- the maximum value of **a** ^ **b**, which is less than a given integer **k**, where
  **a** and **b** are two integers from set **s**.

**Input Format:** The only line contains 2 space-separated integers, **n** and **k**, respectively.

I've written this C program to try to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
    int i, j = 1;
    int maxAND, maxOR, maxXOR = 0;
    int AND, OR, XOR = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            AND = (i & j); OR = (i | j); XOR = (i ^ j);
            if (AND > maxAND && AND < k) { maxAND = AND; }
            if (OR > maxOR && OR < k) { maxOR = OR; }
            if (XOR > maxXOR && XOR < k) { maxXOR = XOR; }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d", maxAND, maxOR, maxXOR);
}

int main() {
    int n, k;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);

    return 0;
}
```

This seems to me like it should work, unfortunately, it prints out

```
2
24
3
```

instead of my expected

```
2
3
3
```

Even weirder, sometimes the program prints out a seemingly random number for maxAND, and will look like

```
1910024400
24
3
```

Here's the doozy: the program prints out what I expect every time when I include debug statements.
If I add this

```
printf("I: %d J: %d OR: %d\n", i, j, OR);
```

at line 13, the program now prints out

```
I: 1 J: 2 OR: 3
I: 1 J: 3 OR: 3
I: 1 J: 4 OR: 5
I: 1 J: 5 OR: 5
I: 2 J: 3 OR: 3
I: 2 J: 4 OR: 6
I: 2 J: 5 OR: 7
I: 3 J: 4 OR: 7
I: 3 J: 5 OR: 7
I: 4 J: 5 OR: 5
2
3
3
```

Which is exactly what I would expect.
Any ideas why this program only outputs what I expect with the inclusion of extra printf's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition of the variables

```
int maxAND, maxOR, maxXOR = 0;
```

you initialize only `maxXOR` with `0`, but `maxAND` and `maxOR` remain uninitialized. Accessing such values later leads to undefined behaviour. Thats what you observe.

Write ...

```
int maxAND = 0, maxOR = 0, maxXOR = 0;
int AND = 0, OR = 0, XOR = 0;
```

or something like that, and it should work consistently.

Note that you must not rely on the compiler to "assign" uninitialized variables the value `0`; it may happen, maybe if you build without optimizations, but this behaviour may change in unpredictable ways, sometimes just by adding another completely unrelated variable. Accessing uninitialized variables is *always* "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that the inline multi-variable decleration would assign the value to all of the max variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your `max` variables are not initialized before the loop starts. It should be:

```
void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
    int i, j = 1;
    int maxAND = 0, maxOR = 0, maxXOR = 0;
    int AND, OR, XOR = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            AND = (i & j); OR = (i | j); XOR = (i ^ j);
            if (AND > maxAND && AND < k) { maxAND = AND; }
            if (OR > maxOR && OR < k) { maxOR = OR; }
            if (XOR > maxXOR && XOR < k) { maxXOR = XOR; }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d", maxAND, maxOR, maxXOR);
}
```